# what type of pressure washer fitting is this

Tags: pressure-washer

I am trying to fix an old hydro surge pressure washer- trying to cut off the detergent line as a replacement wand with two hoses is not available. The pressure washer works just fine. The attached image shows the 'splitter' on the machine- one input is the detergent, and the other the pressurized water.
what type of fitting should i be using, and how to remove the existing one ?
[image]

Comment: Pull out those metal staples (with blue paint* on them) and take a photo of the actual connector end. Including a scale (so we can tell how big it is) may help

(*) possibly locking compound instead of paint.

Comment: The staples are stuck. Any ideas how to get them out?

Comment: inspect the other side, perhaps try pincer pliers.

Comment: what's the black  braided hose on the lower left?

Comment: black braided hose is the detergent/non-pressurized water. I just realized my label "detergent bottle" is pointing  in the wrong direction, as you can see the detergent bottle is near the black hose on the left. sorry for the wrong label. One option that occurred to me- the simplest that I can think of is to cut the black hose and block it off in both directions- This involves the least changes, and the water inlet can be left as is. Thoughts ??